# Is using a standalone SQL file risky as opposed to using full MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, security, sqlite

On my under development website I am using a standalone SQL database file, users.db, to store user login details.

I am wondering though: Should I be using full MySQL integrated to the server like PHPMyAdmin? Is my current "solution" as risky as I think?

I am handling it this way as it means easy access from a number of utilities, including standalone desktop Python programs, via SQLite3 but is this insecure? The file is in my secured cgi-bin but could someone get their hands on it and just download the whole database?

Any and all advice or clarification appreciated,
Ilmiont

Comment: Sure, if your server is insecure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both SQLite and MySQL store their data in some file(s).
Both are insecure if you allow HTTP users to access these files.

Typically, the default configuration of MySQL puts the database files into a separate, non-public directory, while SQLite has no defaults and allows you to put the file anywhere.
But when you are aware of the possible problem, SQLite is as secure as MySQL.
(Checking is easy; just test if http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/users.db works from the outside.)

Comment: Great, thanks for that. I'll keep it how it is for now then.. Just carefully allowing access

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're on a linux machine, not sure about windows, you can set users and file permissions who are allowed access to that file, but you should know what you're doing when it comes to permissions. The other thing that you want to make sure of is the file location. Don't place the file in the web root, place it somewhere else not accessible from the web, but accessible to your app.